# (Done) Use SpringBoot todownload Pdf file，but can't open it

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf

I use SpringBoot to download Pdf file，but can't open it.
And I saw the original file is lager than the download.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzy3d.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHCTL.png)
but I use `IOUtils.copy` to copy stream

```java
filename=pdf_location+filename+".pdf";
BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(filename));
IOUtils.copy(inputStream,out);
```

so I think there might be no bugs in my code :)

SpringBoot `2.4.2`， Apache Common  `2.11.0`，Swagger `knife4j-spring-boot-starter 3.0.2`
When it can't be opened, I check details about this part of code.
About `HttpServletResponse` , the Controller layer

```java
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ fileName + ".pdf");
```

```java
@GetMapping(value = "download/{pdfId}", produces = "application/pdf")
```

And because I use Swagger2 to test firstly, next I try to use browser to open it directly.
Unfortunately, it's the same.
I also change the type of file, the image can be opened...
the image is 6.3mb,but pdf is only 300kb, I can't understand.
If anyone also have this question,or know another ways to download pdf
please give me some suggestions or point my mistake.
really need your help.

Comment: Have you compared the original and the download? In particular, is a large contiguous piece (e.g. the last few KB) missing or several short ranges (e.g. single bytes here and there)?

Comment: @mkl sorry，I didn't compare those，but I just tested the way of using flush() by ur suggestion , it's useful, so i guess it might be the last few KB. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, I find the bug.
In my other function, I turn `ServletOutputStream` into `BufferedOutputStream`
`new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);`
When I just tested, I used `IOUtils.copy(...)` by `ServletOutputStream` directly, the problem has been solved.
But, I don't know why can't the `BufferedOutputStream`, hope somebody can give me some guidance.

Comment: Do you flush the `BufferedOutputStream` explicitly after copying?

Comment: @mkl i just tested it, thx, but now I have another quesion, I tested  transmit the picture morning，it's 6.3MB，lager than pdf file，and I didn't use `flush()`,  why can it be opened also.

Comment: Have you also compared sizes of the image (original and download)?

Comment: appreciate, Im pretty careless，I just saw they are both 6.35MB, but their bytes are different actually. thank u